# React material ui sticky select all in top of the list

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, multi-select

I want to add "select all" option to material ui multiselect which is always show on top of the list even if I have many records and i need to scroll down - like sticky header. I found a solution[how to add select all](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-autocomplete-select-all-kdlpu?file=/src/MultiSelect/MultiSelect.js) but i don't know how to make this option always visible on top. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar, but I needed both a sticky top and bottom. The way I accomplished this was by using the default [basic menu](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-menu/#basic-menu). From there, I put all of my MenuItem items within a MenuList. Now you can add whatever you want above or below the MenuList as either your sticky top or bottom. In order to get the middle section (MenuList) to scroll and to ensure the "sicky" parts below and above, ensure that the MenuList element has a set height and overflow y set to scroll. As long as the limiting height in the CSS is less than enough space for the elements to fit it should force the scroll. Here's an [example built off the default Material UI one](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-morning-bp3ee8?file=/demo.tsx:1144-1152).

In a nutshell this is the minimum you're looking for.

SCSS

```
.overflow-y-scroll{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.height-limit{
  // You want this to be smaller than the amount of space
  // the MenuItem items take up to force the scroll
  height: 300px;
}
```

TSX

```
<Menu>
    id="basic-menu"
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    open={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
    MenuListProps={{
      "aria-labelledby": "basic-button"
    }}
  >
    // Start - Location for sticky headers
    <h3>Sticky Top - Can be div or whatever</h3>
    // NOTE: Without the CSS on this outer MenuList element 
    // it will not work. It doesn't have to be a MenuList it could
    // even be a div so long as it has the appropriate CSS.
    <MenuList className="overflow-y-scroll height-limit">
      // Start - Location scrollable data
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
    </MenuList>
    // End- Location scrollable data
    // Start - Location for sticky footers
    <button type="button">Sticky Bottom</button>
    // End - Location for sticky footers
  </Menu>
```

I didn't make it pretty but did want to show a quick screenshot of what functionally it looks like.

[Screenshot of drop down with Sticky Header and Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFksc.png)